# Função paralela em website

Tags: php, multithreading

Tenho uma classe que gera um arquivo `.xls` para download. O problema é que ele tem mais de 30.000 entradas, então acaba demorando uns 10 minutos para gerar. E nesse tempo tenho que ficar com a página aberta carregando.
Lembro de uns sites que eu usava para converter arquivos nos quais após terminar o upload eu podia fechar a página, o navegador e até desligar o computador que quando o processo estivesse terminado eu iria receber um e-mail com o meu arquivo anexado.
Minha intenção é fazer o mesmo com este arquivo. O usuário clica para fazer download, em seguida é redirecionado para um página que diz que ele vai receber o arquivo no e-mail e enquanto isso ele pode fechar a página e fazer outra coisa.

Em minhas pesquisas acabei encontrando o `pcntl_fork()`, que parecia ser perfeito, até eu descobrir que ele só funciona se eu rodar o `.php` diretamente do terminal. Não encontrei nada que funcione em websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi de uma forma bem simples. Modifiquei o botão de gerar `.xlsx` para que ao invés de gerar, ele chame no terminal o código que gera com `shell_exec("php nomeDoArquivo.php")`, mas mesmo assim ele fica esperando o output do terminal, então acabava demorando igual.

Para resolver isso, como o output do terminal não me interessa¹ eu pedi para ignorá-lo modificando o comando para:

```
$your_command = "php nomeDoArquivo.php";
shell_exec( $your_command . "> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &" );
```

Fonte: [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6140302/2611951)

[1]: Muito cuidado ao ignorar o output, se tiver algum erro no processo você nunca vai saber. Como meu script já envia um email com anexo eu já o configurei para quando der erro enviar um email para mim com a mensagem do erro.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução, talvez não muito elegante, seria colocar esse arquivo numa fila (gerenciada numa tabela de banco de dados e/ou diretório), e no servidor teria um script PHP em cronjob que faria o trabalho de gerar o arquivo e enviar para o email de tempos em tempos.